# MAUI FlexLayout height within VerticalStackLayout

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

Lots of similar questions but they seem to be about FlexLayout nested in FlexLayouts.

I have created a new MAUI App from the template and my first change was to try to add a search box within the main page.

So after the header label I want a search area, which will be a label, an input box, and a go button.

I want them to display on one line if there is room, but wrap on smaller devices, so used a `FlexLayout`.

Trouble is, it only displays if I set a `MinimumHeightRequest` - it's not expanding to fit the content.

However the minimum height required will depend on screen size; I don't want to set a massive height to cover when all elements are stacked vertically because then I'll have empty space on wider devices.

I've tried every `VerticalOptions` and alignment, tried the `ContentView` wrapper as suggested in another post; nothing works. If I swap the `FlexLayout` with another `StackLayout` it displays fine, but obviously doesn't wrap.

Is this a MAUI bug / limitation or can it be made to work?

EDIT for more info:

So my desired result is like this HTML / CSS example: https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/30sem7c9/

As the screen narrows the three elements of the search box start stacking.

The `ScrollView` is there to provide vertical access to any page elements after the search that don't fit. Note that removing it does not change the behaviour.

My XAML is (note I haven't got the textbox in there yet because I can't even get this to work):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="cfMAUIApp1.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="15"
            Padding="10,0"
        >

            <Label
                Text="App"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            />

            <FlexLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua" Wrap="Wrap" >
                <Label
                    Text="Search everywhere"
                    FontSize="18"                   
                />

                <Button
                    x:Name="CounterBtn"
                    Text="Click me"
                    Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                />
            </FlexLayout>
  
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Output, L-R

1. FlexLayout, no minimum height - zero height so doesn't show up at all
2. FlexLayout + min height, wrapped -
   height limited to minimum so squished vertically
3. FlexLayout + min
   height, not wrapped - height expanded to minimum so too high
4. VerticalStackLayout, no minimum height - height correctly auto
   calculated but obviously no responsive / wrapping support

[image]

Comment: Can you show what it currently looks like and what you would like it to look like? Also, what is the purpose of the ScrollView completely on the outside? ScrollViews provide infinite dimensions, which means that automatically adjusting to the screen size will be difficult inside of that.

Comment: Okay added screenshots and an example in CSS of what I'm aiming to achieve